# spyOn gives method does not exist error

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am running a Karma test on an angular app, in the test I have the following:

```
return inject(function($injector) {
   this.Service = {
      functionWithPromise: function(postdata){
         var deferred = $q.defer();
         deferred.resolve({
            data: {}
          });
          return deferred.promise;
         }
      };
};
```

and

```
it('should call the functionWithPromise function when the create function is called', function() {
    res = {}
    this.scope.create(res);
    this.scope.$digest();
    spyOn(Service, "functionWithPromise");
    expect(this.Service.functionWithPromise).toHaveBeenCalled();  
  });
```

when I run the test it gives this error:

```
functionWithPromise() method does not exist
```

How can I get the test to recognize the functionWithPromise() function?

Comment: Did you inject `Service` into your test?

Comment: Yes, I did, sorry, that was a typo in my question. Fixed now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured it out,  I needed to spy on `this.Service` instead of service, like this:

```
spyOn(this.Service, "functionWithPromise");
```